# Need help for an SQL Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

ist the Name of each Supplier with the Location of each Warehouse and the number of Products supplied by that supplier and Stocked at that Warehouse

Answer (score 0):

The tables should be joined together and then a where clause should be applied to filter by the sales rep Jim Burns.

```
select c.name, w.location 
from Salesrep s 
join Warehouse w
on s.Rep_No = w.Rep_No
join Customer c 
on w.Warehouse_No = c.Warehouse_No
where s.Name = 'Jim Burns'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, i just tried it out and it worked, totally forgot about joining the tables together. Thank you once again.

Comment: would a join be needed for a query like this too?                       List the Name of each Supplier with the Location of each Warehouse and the number of Products supplied by that supplier and Stocked at that Warehouse.

Comment: This query is performing a join.  Which query are you referring to?

Comment: List the Name of each Supplier with the Location of each Warehouse and the number of Products supplied by that supplier and Stocked at that Warehouse.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    c.Name,
    w.Location   
FROM  salesrep as s
LEFT JOIN warehouse as w ON w.Rep_No = s.Rep_No
LEFT JOIN Customer as c ON c.Warehouse_No = w.Warehouse_No
WHERE s.Name = 'Rep Jim Burns';
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me out with the query.